# Java Applet: free up Graphics resources

Tags: java, graphics, applet

My program displays image gallery, unfortunatelly it loads everything at once. I am looking for suggestions to implement a method to load an image and release previous loaded image once user clicks next button.

Updates version where I changed to JApplet and changed the way paint method is called. However it still does not solve an issue with memory usage. Any help would be highly appriciated!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class JAppletGallery extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private Button first;
    private Button previous;
    private Button next;
    private Button last;

    static int total = 400; // initial total total images
    int imageIndex = 0; // current image

    // gets folder's location
    String folderName = "/Users/Martynas/Pictures/leicester/";
    File folder = new File(folderName);

    // initialise image object up to its total
    Image Pictures[] = new Image[total];
    static String[] imageName = new String[total];

    // constructor
    public JAppletGallery() {

    }

    public void init() {
        makeGui();
        prepareImages();
    }

    private void makeGui() {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(800, 600);

        // init buttons
        first = new Button("First");
        first.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        previous = new Button("Previous");
        previous.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        next = new Button("Next");
        next.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        last = new Button("Last");
        last.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        // init panel holder
        Panel btnPanel = new Panel();

        btnPanel.add(first);
        btnPanel.add(previous);
        btnPanel.add(next);
        btnPanel.add(last);

        add(BorderLayout.NORTH, btnPanel);

        first.addActionListener(this);
        previous.addActionListener(this);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        last.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void drawNext() {

        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1;
        // checks for current image
        if (imageIndex == total) {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
        // sends index to display image
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawPrevious() {
        imageIndex = imageIndex - 1;

        if (imageIndex < 0) {
            imageIndex = total - 1;
        }
        repaint();

    }

    public void drawFirst() {
        imageIndex = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawLast() {
        imageIndex = total - 1;
        repaint();
    }


    // Manage button actions
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == previous) {
            drawPrevious();
        } else if (e.getSource() == next) {
            drawNext();
        } else if (e.getSource() == first) {
            drawFirst();
        } else if (e.getSource() == last) {
            drawLast();
        }
    }

    // gets files from a folder - sub-method of displayImage()
    public static void filesFolder(File folder) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        int index = 0;

        // puts image names in separate index of array
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                // System.out.println(file.getName());
                // assigning to String array for further manipulation
                imageName[index] = file.getName();
                index++;
            }
        }
        // total images count correction
        total = index;
    }

    private void prepareImages() {
        // gets image names from the folder
        filesFolder(folder);

        for (int p = 0; p < total; p++) {

            Pictures[p] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), folderName + imageName[p]);
        }       
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Pictures[imageIndex], 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response. First things first, don't use `getGraphics`, this is not how custom painting should be done

Comment: I just provided an example of my whole program. Suggest me a better method, instead of using Graphics to load images one by one and to save pc resources, especially RAM as it loads all images at once. Thank you

Comment: Is it possible to achieve desired result by adding JLabel and using JIcon?

Comment: Yes and it probably be preferred,but you'll need to use a JApplet instead. Also, Applets usually run in a secure sand box, this, generally, means that they won't have access to the filesystem. You should only be loading the images you need when you need them, not all at once

Comment: `Graphics g = imageCanvas.getGraphics();`  Wrong!  Paint when told to in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Otherwise only schedule a paint with a call to `repaint()`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it was useful, to redo paint() method bit, however it does not solve memory usage issue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove instance variable

// initialise image object up to its total
    Image Pictures[] = new Image[total];

Or at least on next and previous - remove elements more than n places away from current. You are caching all images now.

Instead make some of the Pictures variable's index null. In paint check if its null - if it is load image of that slot alone.

Also consider reading up on naming conventions and camel case - name instance variables being with lower case so picutures and not Pictures. You have done that for other vars so maybe just typo here :-)

And dont mix java awt components with swing. can use

java.awt.BorderLayout; java.awt.Color; java.awt.Graphics; java.awt.Image; etc

but not components like Panel, Button use JButton ...

It takes more memory when you try to release ... until garbage collection takes place. A good idea if you have more than 20 images i guess, so maybe cache size can be 10.

Sample code - made into an app can make into a Japplet again - getdocument base etc

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class JAppletGallery extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private JButton first;
    private JButton previous;
    private JButton next;
    private JButton last;
    private int cacheSize = 2;
    static int total = 400; // initial total total images
    int imageIndex = 0; // current image
    String msg = "";

    // gets folder's location
    String folderName = "/Users/Martynas/pictures/leicester/";
    File folder = new File(folderName);

    // initialise image object up to its total
    Image pictures[] = new Image[total];
    static String[] imageName = new String[total];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JAppletGallery ap = new JAppletGallery();
        if(args.length > 0){
            ap.folderName = args[0];

        }
        ap.folder = new File(ap.folderName);

        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Gal ");

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
            //f.setDefaultCloseAction
                f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
                f.getContentPane().add(ap);
                f.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 700);
                ap.setBounds(15, 15, 675, 675);//not a good way but fine for testing/ local
                //slp(1500)
                f.setVisible(true);

                ap.init();
                ap.start();
                f.invalidate();
                f.repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    // constructor
    public JAppletGallery() {

    }

    public void init() {
        makeGui();
        prepareImages();
    }

    private void makeGui() {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(800, 600);

        // init buttons
        first = new JButton("First");
        first.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        previous = new JButton("Previous");
        previous.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        next = new JButton("Next");
        next.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        last = new JButton("Last");
        last.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        // init panel holder
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
        btnPanel.add(first);
        btnPanel.add(previous);
        btnPanel.add(next);
        btnPanel.add(last);

        add(BorderLayout.NORTH, btnPanel);
        ImgShow imgs = new ImgShow();
        imgs.parent = this;
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, imgs);

        first.addActionListener(this);
        previous.addActionListener(this);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        last.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void drawNext() {

        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1;
        // checks for current image
        if (imageIndex == total) {
            imageIndex = 0;
        }
        picsLoadAndTrim();
        // sends index to display image
        repaint();
    }

    public void drawPrevious() {
        imageIndex = imageIndex - 1;

        if (imageIndex < 0) {
            imageIndex = total - 1;
        }
        picsLoadAndTrim();
        repaint();

    }

    private void picsLoadAndTrim() {

        int before = imageIndex - cacheSize;
        int before2 = total;
        if(before < 0){
            before2 = total + before;
        }
        int after = imageIndex + cacheSize;
        int after2 = -1;
        if(after >= total){
            after2 = after - total;
        }
        System.out.println("total " + total + " imageIndex " + imageIndex  + ", before " + before + ", after " + after + ", before2 " + before2+ ", after2 " + after2);
        for(int i =0; i < total ; i++){
            if((i >= before && i <= after) ||  (i <= after2) || (i >= before2)){
                System.out.println("CHECK " + i);
                if(pictures[i] ==null){//load only if not currently loaded

                    try {
                        pictures[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(folder, imageName[i]));
                    //loadImage(getDocumentBase()  , imageName[i]);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        msg = msg + " " + imageName[i];
                    }
                }else{
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("rel " + i);
                pictures[i] = null; //release if loaded before
            }
        }
    }

    public URL getDocumentBase(){
        URL u = null;//super.getDocumentBase();
        try{
            if(u==null)u = new URL("file://" + folderName);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return u;
    }
    public void drawFirst() {
        imageIndex = 0;
        picsLoadAndTrim();
        repaint();

    }

    public void drawLast() {
        imageIndex = total - 1;
        picsLoadAndTrim();
        repaint();
    }


    // Manage button actions
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == previous) {
            drawPrevious();
        } else if (e.getSource() == next) {
            drawNext();
        } else if (e.getSource() == first) {
            drawFirst();
        } else if (e.getSource() == last) {
            drawLast();
        }
    }

    // gets files from a folder - sub-method of displayImage()
    public  void filesFolder(File folder) {
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        int index = 0;

        // puts image names in separate index of array
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            String s = file.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (file.isFile() && (s.endsWith(".png") || s.endsWith("jpg"))) {
                // System.out.println(file.getName());
                // assigning to String array for further manipulation
                imageName[index] = file.getName();
                index++;
            }
        }
        // total images count correction
        total = index;
        if(cacheSize > total)cacheSize = total;
    }

    private void prepareImages() {
        // gets image names from the folder
        filesFolder(folder);
        picsLoadAndTrim();
        //for (int p = 0; p < 1; p++) {

          //  pictures[p] = getImage(getDocumentBase(), folderName + imageName[p]);
        //}
    }



}

class ImgShow extends JComponent{
    JAppletGallery parent;


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            if(parent.pictures[parent.imageIndex] != null){
                g.drawImage(parent.pictures[parent.imageIndex], 0, 35, this);
            }else{
                g.drawString(parent.msg, 10, 35);
                //err
            }
    }
}
```

This code can be impvoed but it shows you release/ making null.

Comment: Thats just amazing, so much to learn and understand about possible improvements! By the way, why usage of RAM greately increases compare with slow button click as once you start quickly pressing Next button? Does garbage collection fail to free up efficiently as it havent got much time to evaluate? This is a bit off topic, just for my own interest. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes objects are unreferenced but the jvm sees no reason to reclaim it as anyway the program does not need more. when it does it will free. not the most appealing way when you want it to free it up. Could try a request to System.gc(); after the loop that frees up and a Thread.sleep(1000); within a try-catch. but that might or not help. Rememberno need to do this in anything but academic interest. another choice is to change the garbage collection jvm options when starting the program. i know they exist but you can google about